# Xcode/iOS - Trying a simple print to console debug, can't get it to work. No clue how to find the issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, debugging

I've been following the tutorial to the T on Apple's website: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH19-SW1

Bear with me as I've never asked an iOS development question on SO before (I'm only just starting out), but here is my storyboard so far:

[image]

Touching (or in this case, clicking) the red square should print a message to the Xcode debug console (see code below):

ViewController.swift:

```
    import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Handle the text field’s user input through delegate callbacks.
        nameTextField.delegate = self
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

   // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField) {
        mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
    }
   // MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage
        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
   // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(sender: UIButton) {
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    }
}
```

RatingControl.swift:

```
import UIKit

class RatingControl: UIView {

   // MARK: Initialization
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 44, height: 44))

        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(RatingControl.ratingButtonTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchDown)

        addSubview(button)
    }
    override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 240, height: 44)
    }

    // MARK: Button Action
    func ratingButtonTapped(button: UIButton) {
        print("Button pressed ")
    }

}
```

When running the simulator, clicking on the red button (which is set to the class RatingControl) does nothing, nor prints anything to the console.

I'm only just starting Xcode/Swift so I'm not sure if I've provided all the relevant info, so please let me know if there's any more info I need to provide. Thank you!

Comment: How are you adding the RatingControl to your view?  Through the storyboard?  I pasted your code into a test project and I get a console message when I click the red square.

Comment: Check `userInterationEnabled` on your `RatingControl` is set to true (either in the storyboard, or in your code)

Comment: @originaluser2 that was my first thought too, but it defaults to true for UIView.  It is still worth checking in case they have accidentally turned it off.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in the `ratingButtonTapped` function and see if the function is being called.

Comment: User Interaction Enabled is checked. Correct me if I'm using the wrong terminology, but I added RatingControl as a class through a file named RatingControl.swift. (seen in the code in the original post)

Comment: @Paulw11 At least the code is working as intended! Maybe I am misunderstanding how to use Xcode and Simulator then.

Comment: Xcode has a very powerful debugger built in that can let you see what your app is doing.  You should make yourself familiar with it.  There's plenty of information on the web.  Here is one video I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n9vAsEWRsOM

Comment: Check the hierarchy of your views in the storyboard - make sure all the superviews of your `RatingControl` have `userInteractionEnabled` set to true (As Paul said, it's possible you may have accidentally disabled it on a view). Also you may have accidentally added it as a subview to a `UIImageView`, which defaults to `userInteractionEnabled` being false.

Comment: Try deleting the app in the simulator and re-running the app from Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exactly the same issue as following the same tutorial.

This is what you need: View > Debug Area > Activate Console. (cmd + shift + c)

Answer (score 1):

For `XCode v11` + SwiftUI users who find the issue the original poster explained you'll have to activate `Debugging` in your `Live preview`. Here's an example, assuming that you have the `view > debug area > activate console`:

[image]